# Display Text from Firebase in a Textformfield?

Tags: firebase, flutter, text

I just wanted to display the Username from the User which is saved in the cloud Firestore. Does anyone know how to display the Username String in the cloud Firestore?

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  lol()async{
    var documents =
    (await Firestore.instance.collection('SerX').get())
    .docs;
  }

  return  Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
        bottom: PreferredSize(
            child: Container(
              color: Colors.blue,
              height: 4.0,
            ),
            preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(0)),
        backgroundColor: Colors.black,
        leading: IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back ,color: Colors.blue,),onPressed: (){
          Navigator.pushReplacement(context,
              MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => HomeScreen()));
        },),
        title: Text('Profile', style: TextStyle(
          color:Colors.white,
          fontSize: 25,
          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
          fontFamily: 'Orbitron',
        ),
          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
        ),
      ),
    body: Container(
      color: Colors.black,
      child: ListView(
        children: [
          Stack(
            children: [
              Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(140,100,0,0),
                width: 130,
                height: 130,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    border: Border.all(
                        width: 3,
                        color: Colors.blue,
                    ),
                    boxShadow: [BoxShadow(
                      spreadRadius: 2, blurRadius: 10,
                      color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.1),
                      offset: Offset(0,10),
                    ),
                    ],
                    shape: BoxShape.circle,
                    image: DecorationImage(
                      fit: BoxFit.cover,
                      image: (_image != null) ? FileImage(
                          _image)
                          : NetworkImage("https://www.senertec.de/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/blank-profile-picture-973460_1280.png"),
                    )
                ),
              ),
              Positioned(
                bottom: 0,
                right: 150,
                child: Container(
                  height: 40,
                  width: 40,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    border: Border.all(width: 2, color: Colors.blue),
                    shape: BoxShape.circle,
                    color: Colors.white,
                  ),
                  child: IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.edit), color: Colors.blue, onPressed: (){
                    getImage(context);
                  },),
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
          SizedBox(height: 40),
          TextFormField(
            style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.white,
              fontSize: 15,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              fontFamily: 'Orbitron',
              ),
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                borderSide: const BorderSide(color: Colors.blue, width: 1.0),
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25.0),
              ),
              enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
              borderSide: const BorderSide(color: Colors.white, width: 1.0),
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25.0),
            ),
              icon: Icon(Icons.edit, color: Colors.blue,),
              contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 3),
              labelText: "Username",
              labelStyle: TextStyle(color:  Colors.white),
              floatingLabelBehavior: FloatingLabelBehavior.always,
              prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.account_circle, color: Colors.blue,),
      ->      hintText: snapshot.data.data()["Username"],    <-
              hintStyle: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.white,
                fontSize: 15,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                fontFamily: 'Orbitron',
              ),
            ),
          ),
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using firebase user authentication then with the help of firebaseUser you can easily access the user username.
Else if you are using database like firestore then the data you get from that is in JSON format (like Maps).

> String userName = firebaseData['userName'];

Comment: Where I have to put this line ?